# Resetting SQL Window's length when flag is True?

Tags: python, sql, if-statement, partition

I have a table of utility bill segments, where each segment tells a month's kwh usage. I'd like to sum groups of 12 together to get annual bills.

The variable *bill_cd* indicates the last segment of the annual bill.
[Data download](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/darrenkeeley/stackoverflow/master/so_ex.csv)

```
    cust_id     kwh    bill_cd
0   3333    1104.388683 ?
1   3333    1498.007305 ?
2   3333    662.044822  ?
3   3333    661.342412  ?
4   3333    494.070683  ?
5   3333    300.147843  ?
6   3333    836.677007  ?
7   3333    864.608037  ?
8   3333    933.232845  ?
9   3333    1191.025358 ?
10  3333    1507.119588 ?
11  3333    1980.653631 BILL
12  3333    2621.387010 ?
13  3333    2552.053789 BILL
```

The problem: as can be seen, there aren't 12 segments per annual bill. In this snippet, I'd like to only get the sum of the first annual bill since it will include 12 segments, but not the second because it only has two segments.

I wrote this query in python:

```
import pandas as pd, pandasql as ps

df = pd.read_csv('so_ex.csv')

q1 = """
select cust_id, kwh, bill_cd,
sum(kwh) over (partition by cust_id
    rows between 11 preceding and current row) as kwh_total,
count(kwh) over (partition by cust_id
    rows between 11 preceding and current row) as bseg_count
from df
"""

ps.sqldf(q1, locals())
```

And the result is below. Is there a way to make the count variable reset after passing an instance of "BILL" so that the bill segment count will go to 1. This way, I could filter the table later where bseg_count=12.

```
   cust_id      kwh   bill_cd  kwh_total bseg_count
0   3333    1104.388683 ?   1104.388683   1
1   3333    1498.007305 ?   2602.395988   2
2   3333    662.044822  ?   3264.440810   3
3   3333    661.342412  ?   3925.783223   4
4   3333    494.070683  ?   4419.853906   5
5   3333    300.147843  ?   4720.001748   6
6   3333    836.677007  ?   5556.678755   7
7   3333    864.608037  ?   6421.286792   8
8   3333    933.232845  ?   7354.519638   9
9   3333    1191.025358 ?   8545.544996   10
10  3333    1507.119588 ?   10052.664584  11
11  3333    1980.653631 BILL 12033.318215 12
12  3333    2621.387010 ?    13550.316542 12
13  3333    2552.053789 BILL 14604.363026 12
```

Desired output:

```
   cust_id      kwh   bill_cd  kwh_total bseg_count
0   3333    1104.388683 ?   1104.388683   1
1   3333    1498.007305 ?   2602.395988   2
2   3333    662.044822  ?   3264.440810   3
3   3333    661.342412  ?   3925.783223   4
4   3333    494.070683  ?   4419.853906   5
5   3333    300.147843  ?   4720.001748   6
6   3333    836.677007  ?   5556.678755   7
7   3333    864.608037  ?   6421.286792   8
8   3333    933.232845  ?   7354.519638   9
9   3333    1191.025358 ?   8545.544996   10
10  3333    1507.119588 ?   10052.664584  11
11  3333    1980.653631 BILL 12033.318215 12
12  3333    2621.387010 ?    13550.316542 1
13  3333    2552.053789 BILL 14604.363026 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a cumulative count of `BILL` in reverse to define groups and then use `row_number()`:

```
select df.*,
       row_number() over (partition by cust_id, grp order by <ordering col> desc)
from (select df.*,
             sum(case when bill_cd = 'BILL' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by cust_id order by <ordering col>) as grp
      from df
     ) df
```

These window functions should be based on an ordering column (such as a date or sequential id).  It is not clear what that column is.

Comment: This was very fast and very close, thank you! But I realize I didn't word the question well. I updated the question with the desired result. I hope have the counter reset after *passing* BILL, since BILL marks the last segment of an annual bill.

Comment: @DDDD . . . This is a simple adjustment.  Just use a descending sort.

Comment: I had the same realization over dinner last night. Thanks!